# Adding Date and Time into Datetime datatype in mySQL

Tags: html, mariadb

I am not able to find the syntax to add the current Date and Time Stamp (Of the server) into the SQL Table.

I tried using these syntaxes to update my table to add current date/time value to the table I made for a LAMP Server login page. Any help would be appreciated.

```
UPDATE users
SET timestamp = '2008-11-11 13:23:44'
WHERE username = '"arunsharma"'
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsTyk.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsTyk.png

Comment: Please include your original queries and data as _text_, directly in the question, formatted with four or more spaces on each line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question borders on being a typo question, but string literals in MySQL are represented just with single quotes, not double quotes wrapped again in single quotes.  So here is one of your queries corrected:

```
UPDATE users SET timestamp = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() WHERE username = 'arunsharma';
```

Comment: Perfect! Thankyou so much!

Comment: See also `NOW()`.